# Jenkins BuildResultTrigger doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, build-triggers

I can't figure why my job is not triggering nightly.  In Jenkins have 2 jobs set up intended to function in the following way

**Job 1: DataCheck**

> Runs every hour runs a check to see if data is consistent.

**Job 2: MoveDataToProduction**

> Every Day at 8pm moves data to production as long as the most recent **DataCheck** job has passed

I'm using a BuildResultTrigger in **MoveDataToProduction** , with the Job to monitor **DataCheck**.  The Job Build result is **SUCCESS**.  The schedule is `H 20 * * *`.

Now, I can see the BuildResultTrigger running a check at 8pm, but even if the **DataCheck** job last run is success the  **MoveDataToProduction** does not run.  Here's all I see:

```
Polling started on Nov 19, 2014 8:00:00 PM
Polling for the job MoveDataToProduction
Recording context. Check changes in next poll.

Polling complete. Took 0 ms.
No changes.
```

Will the SUCCESS of **DataCheck** only be picked up if it changed from a failure state or something?  Ideally, my  **DataCheck** should never fail, but I still want the **MoveDataToProduction** to trigger.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but in my case the downstream job didn't run because there had not been a new instance of the upstream job. I didn't understand that the BuildResultTrigger does nothing if the job it's testing hasn't been run since the last polling interval. Not sure if this applies in your case -- from your description it shouldn't in general, but it might depending how you were testing.